# AppBar component of material-ui package not working in my react js application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am creating my first React Application (WebApp) and I have following issue.
I want a Navigation Bar and therefore I am using the AppBar component of the material-ui lib. I used the the example **Simple App Bar** explained on the official [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/) page.

If I compile and run the app I get the following result:
[image]

Why it doesn't look like the example on the website, althought I used the same code. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

My js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} 
color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import ButtonAppBar from './Components/ButtonAppBar';

ReactDOM.render(
 <ButtonAppBar/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );

reportWebVitals();
```

UPDATE: I found the cause of my problem. I had an import of a component in my index.js file (which was not used). This component had a .css file attached which overruled the style of the AppBar.
I didn't know the .css file of a not used component has an impact, but I was wrong ^^

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So as for why the color is not matching with documentation is because Material UI documentation uses it's own custom theme https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/, you can go to palette > Primary to get the exact color code.
2. As for why your nav bar looks like that I don't know I compiled the same code but got the desired result except the color, here's the code https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-2xp1q?file=/demo.js